# DLL not found fake error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am getting error:

> *Could not load file or assembly 'StructureDLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.*

on runtime (not when build). However, DLL **is** placed next to EXE. I am using 2 DLLs, but only one throws an error. Do you know any possible reason?

Keep in mind that:

- Both are in the solution
- Both are next to EXE output
- Both are added through Reference in VS

Thank you,

EDIT 1:
I've noticed that there is reference to `IESHIMS.DLL` that is missing. Where it come from? I am using only following references, as usual, and never had such error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
```

EDIT2 (Answer!)

I've noticed that rename of main DLL caused that error. I've changed "StructureDLL.dll" to "Structure.dll" before adding to project. I seem to be dumb.

Comment: "or one of its dependencies" you're probably missing an assembly that is referenced by StructureDLL. Check the Configuration MAnager if the Build checkbox has been set.

Comment: The answer is in the error itself: `or one of its dependencies`.

Comment: References for this DLL are: `Microsoft.CSharp` and `System`.

Comment: @AnantDabhi Because references appears already in other projects without causing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to check it's dependencies by [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com). This piece of software shows you hidden dependencies. It helped me many times.

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: right, but it may help him to find the solution himself. Dependency walker was my first thought too reading this question.